# position absolute bottom 0 iphone scrolling issue

Tags: jquery, ios, css

http://bvh.delineamultimedia.com/?page_id=2 -> On this page I have a jQuery animation to show the footer when you click on the arrow to the right it shows content then closes when you click the arrow again. Everything is working fine until you view it on the iPhone.

On the iphone when you scroll up and DON'T click on the arrow it displays the content for a split second then snaps to the proper spot… is there a way to avoid this? Has anyone else ran into this?

Comment: I believe this is a function of how iOS handles scrolling. I would use [`position:fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position) in your CSS instead.

Comment: Okay I've changed it and am still having the same issues. Here is my CSS on my container. 

position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;

Comment: I agree with fixed. I'm not sure what's governing these elements but it could be an issue with `z-index`, especially if jquery is hiding/showing the content.